# Android webview : "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined"

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

I'm writing an android app that should be putting the address into the search field of a local delivery website, in order for me to fetch the available restaurants. For this I'm trying to fill the search using some javascript inside a webview but when submitting the form get the following error: 
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'types' of undefined", source: https://deliveroo.fr/fr/ (12)

The error also repeats itself if I click the button by myself. The website appears to work normally inside the same webview if I fill in the address manually. Any help is much appreciated. Already tried everything that I found from similar questions, like activating DomStorage or cleaning cash.

My code:

```
final WebView web = webView;
        web.clearCache(true);
        web.clearHistory();
        web.getSettings().setSaveFormData(false);
        web.clearFormData();
        web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);

        web.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
            {super.onPageFinished(web, url);
final String js = "javascript:" + "document.getElementsByName('address_search')[0].value = '" + address + "';" + "document.getElementById('find_food').click();";

                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
                        view.evaluateJavascript(js,null);
                    }else {view.loadUrl(js);
                    }

            }
        });

        web.loadUrl("https://deliveroo.fr/fr/");
```

Website code:

```
<div class="landing-index-page-search__container" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1">
    <h1 class="landing-index-page-search--main-title" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.0">Vos restaurants préférés, livrés en moins de 30 minutes.</h1>
    <form method="get" action="" class="landing-index-page-search--form landing-index-page-search--non-postcode" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2">
    <span data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.0"></span>
    <div data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1">
    <div class="landing-index-page-search--input" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1">
    <div class="landing-index-page-search--input address-search" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.1">
    <input name="address_search" type="text" tabindex="-1" class="" placeholder="Saisissez votre adresse" value=" " data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.1.0"/></div>
    <input id="find_food" type="submit" value="Voir les restaurants" class="button" data-reactid=".1d1c1t7z20w.2.0.0.1.1.2.1.1.2"/>
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Comment: same issue with me :( found any answer?